# how remove a class after an ajax load using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how remove a class after an ajax load using jquery?

First thing, I load an html file containing only list information into a ul id of ul_list

```
        $("#ul_list").load("testListResults");
```

Next, I try to remove all highlight class file:

```
        $("#ul_list li").removeClass("highLight"); // this is not working, still see the list background high light color.
```

Next, I try to get the text information of the first list.

```
       $("#ul_list li:first").text();  // this is not working either, showing empty.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your changes to the call back function. This will ensure the scripts are not ran until the ajax load is complete.

```
$("#ul_list").load("testListResults", function(){
   $("#ul_list li").removeClass("highLight");
   $("#ul_list li:first").text();
});
```

With regards to your second point, I don't know what you're trying to do with `$("#ul_list li:first").text();` as your not assigning it to a variable, but try `.html()` instead:

```
$("#ul_list li:first").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ul_list").load("testListResults", function() {
    $("#ul_list li").removeClass("highLight");
    $("#ul_list li:first").text();
});
```